# ASA 5555-X ACL confusion

Tags: cisco-asa

I'm wondering what this access list means on the ASA 5555-X?

access-list TEST_INSIDE extended permit udp host 192.168.1.99 eq 7600 host 192.168.1.1

I am confused about the 'eq 7600' part since I usually see that at the end of the ACL and not in the middle.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you asking if the syntax is valid, or literally what it means?

Comment: I'd like to know what it means.

Answer (score 1):

I read that ACE as representing "any UDP traffic from 192.168.1.99 to 192.168.1.1, *provided it came **from** port 7600*".

TCP and UDP traffic have both source address/port and a destination address/port.  The client binds to the source port on its own network adapter and then to the destination port on the server's adapter.  The server sends the reply to the client's own port.

Access-lists reflect this by also having both a source address/port and destination address/port tuple.  However, you can omit either port value from the `access-list` line.  This omission is taken to mean "*any* port".

In an `access-list` where the `eq 7600` part is at the *end* of the line, it would mean that the *destination* port had to be 7600.  I would agree that this is more common when allowing traffic through a firewall, because usually a *server* listens on one explicit port (e.g. a web server on TCP/80) and the *client* makes a request by binding to any ephemeral port in its own network stack.

However, it is possible that this rule was designed to allow a service protocol where the server opens a dynamic port and *tells the client* which port it opened.  Active-mode FTP is a good example of a protocol like this (although it is usually sourced from TCP/20, not UDP/7600).  With a protocol like this, the firewall admin cannot know beforehand which port the server will open, and so has to open all of them.  However, many better firewalls can inspect the well-known protocols, determine when this is happening and open ports dynamically just for the port sent by the server.  Cisco call this an inspection policy or a fixup (depending on model/version).  However, not all protocols (especially encrypted/TLS traffic) can be inspected.

Of course, what this `access-list` *actually* means will depend on what it is bound to.  If it is bound to an interface with an `access-group` statement, it would mean that only this traffic is allowed to enter (or exit) that interface.  However, this particular `access-list` might have been used to describe a packet capture filter or even a policy match for connection-specific properties, such as keep-alives or quality-of-service.

You should look through your config to find if there are any other lines that explicitly reference that `TEST_INSIDE` name.  Doing so may provide some more context.

(If asked to guess, I would posit that this rule may have been written to implement a streaming video or a VOiP service -- those can be pretty dynamic and tend to use UDP -- but that *is* just a guess.)